# Remove brackets [] array map in php

Tags: php, arrays, sqlite, dictionary, object

please I need help.
I'm using the map function to extract values ​​from an array, the structure is as follows:

```
//This is my backend
    public function downloadChat(){
    $current_id = Auth::id();
    $list = Chat::where(function ($filter1) use ( $current_id)  {
        $filter1->where('id_current_utente',$current_id)
          ->where(function ($filter2)  {
            $filter2->where('id_view', '=',2)
            ->orWhere('id_view', '=',1);
          
            });
     })
        ->orWhere(function ($filter) use ( $current_id) {
                   $filter->where('id_utente', $current_id)
                   ->where(function ($filter3)  {
                    $filter3->where('id_view', '=',1)
                    ->orWhere('id_view', '=',3);
                });
         })
    
     ->orderBy('chats.created_at', 'desc')
     ->select('users.id', 'users.name', 'users.cognome','chats.edit')
     ->get();
     $arraylist=$list->map(function($item) {                                    
        $value=[$item->id, $item->name, $item->cognome, $item->edit];
       
        return json_encode($value);
        
    });
    
        return $arraylist;
      
}
```

This is the request I make from my frontend

```
    async downloadChat({commit}) {
        return axios.get(API_URL + 'downloadChat',{ headers: authHeader() })
            .then(res => {
                console.log(res.data);
               $output= [ "[4217,null]", "[4216,null]", "[4215,200]"]
            })
    },
```

My problem is that I have to insert these values ​​into a sql table, but because of the brackets [], it throws me an error. I tried to convert the array to string and it works fine, but the problem that the edit column might have null value and it is essential that in the database it is saved as null.

```
//FRONTEND Insert multiple value
INSERT INTO chats (id,edit) VALUES ${$OUTPUT};
```

To work well, I would need an output like this:

```
$output= ((4217,null), (4216,null), (4215,200))
```

Is there a way to replace brackets [] with brackets ()? Or do you have any better ideas? Thanks for the help

Comment: Your `$array` definition is not valid PHP code and your `$array->map()` reference doesn't make sense in this context because `$array` is not an object. This code can't possibly work as shown. Run `var_dump($array);` to determine what it's actually an instance of.

Comment: Your original array as you call it looks like a JSON String without the quotes that would make it a string! Could it be a JSON String that you are starting with?

Comment: the array variable is actually obtained from model::where()->get(); in laravel.
The one I reported above was just an example to shorten the code

Comment: Ok, but we need accurate information so we can know whats going on and even try to test an answer before giving one

Comment: Also a PHP array does not have a `map` method. Is there something else going on here that you have not told us about

Comment: Ok thanks, now I'll try to explain myself better. On my laravel backend I have to take some values ​​from my chat model, key: 'id' and 'edit' and extract the respective values. Later I send these values ​​to ionic frontend where I am using @capacitor-community/sqlite plugin and store this data in my local database. If I save the value as a string it works correctly, but the problem occurs when the edit value is null and in the frontend db I find an empty string field instead of the null value

Comment: what if you do this:

`$value = '(' . $item->id . ',' . $item->name . ',' . $item->cognome . ',' . $item->edit . ')';`
`return $value;`

and right after map append this:

`->reduce(function ($prev, $curr) {`
    `return $prev . ',' . $curr;`
`});`

if you require a null to be written there, you could add a condition to store a string 'null' if any variable is empty.

Comment: @Oukaasha Habib this works well, it gives me the desired result, I just have to figure out how to insert the condition when the value is null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seems to be your JSON encoding each row item, which then it will be double-encoded once you respond,

Ending up like `["[4217,null]","[4216,null]",[4215,200]"]`

Not `((4217,null), (4216,null), (4215,200))` :/

Is these lines:

```
$arraylist=$list->map(function($item) {                                    
   $value=[$item->id, $item->name, $item->cognome, $item->edit];
   return json_encode($value);
});
return $arraylist;
```

Instead, just do:

```
return $list->map(fn($item) => [$item->id, $item->name, $item->cognome, $item->edit]);
```

Let the response handler JSON encode the array, then it'll be `[[4217,null],[4216,null],[4215,200]]`, which fixes `res.data` to what you want an array of arrays, not array of strings

Comment: the problem is that on my frontend, sql only accepts me this
`((4217,null), (4216,null), (4215,200))`
instead if I use this
`[[4217,null],[4216,null],[4215,200]]`
 it gives me an error near the brackets []
I am using this instruction, is it correct?

INSERT INTO chats VALUES ${res.data}

Comment: what's the error?, it seems you are confusing clientside with serverside code, when you `axios.put('/chat/1',{ name: 'abc', edit: 1 })` up from axios (which your not showing), it would be in Laravel Request object `$name = $request->input('name');` etc see https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/requests#retrieving-input, `$request->route('id')` for id, then you use them vars to insert or update the row

Comment: though if you want `((4217,null), (4216,null), (4215,200))` do this https://playcode.io/1211822

Comment: Thanks a lot it works perfectly. One last question if I may, can't this solution be done in php? Because in javascript I have to manage it on the frontend, if it's possible I'd prefer to do it on the frontend, anyway thanks to all